# GET запрос к CGI скрипту в Python не возвращает ожидаемый результат

Tags: python, http, get, cgi

Имеется простенькая форма, и скрипт, который обрабатывает данные от этой формы.

Форма:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Форма</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="cgi-bin/script.py" method="get">
    <table cellpadding="4">
        <tr>
            <td>Номер:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="oid">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

if "oid" not in form:
    print("<H1>Error</H1>")
else:
    print(form["oid"].value)
```

Т.е. когда скрипту передается GET запрос вида script.py?oid=123 скрипт, должен вывести значение oid, но этого не происходит. Вот, что показывает лог сервера (сервер запущен так: python3 -m http.server --cgi):

> 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Nov/2016 10:44:40] "GET /forma.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Nov/2016 10:44:43] "GET /cgi-bin/script.py?oid=1234 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Nov/2016 10:44:43] command: "C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe" -u C:\Users......\cgi-bin\script.py
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Nov/2016 10:44:44] CGI script exited OK

Но при этом, я не получаю вывода "1234".
Где у меня ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Не хватает

```
print("Content-Type: text/plain\n")
```

Перед

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

Comment: `<h1>Error</h1>` в коде намекает, что `Content-Type: text/html`. А ошибка в том, что http заголовки от тела должны быть `"\r\n\r\n"` отделены (`print("\n")` как раз это разделитель и печатает у вас).